# how to stop duplicate record in text file in C# windows form

Tags: c#, file

how to stop duplicate record in text file in C# windows form?
I have text file text.txt and there are records. before insert new record in the file i want to search the records in the file if duplicate then dont enter. else insert new record.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can search the text file using regular expressions.
Here is small code snippet for that:

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("index.txt");
 byte[] text = new byte[stream.Length];
 stream.Read(text, 0, (int)stream.Length);
var searchValue = "new record";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

 string content = encoding.GetString(text);
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content,
  searchValue);

 foreach( Match match in matches )
 {
  Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
 }
```

You can transform it to a method that will return what you need - if there is a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a lot of records at once then I would probably read the entire file and save it in the memory.

Read the whole thing into a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which would prevent you from saving duplicate records.

Once you have the file`s Dictionary , check if your record already exists by using [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).